# Mysql sum and subtract query

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query which is sum all orders, but subtract where ID 80, for example

I try this

```
SELECT SUM(Orders) FROM MyBuyers WHERE ID=80 NOT IN
```

but they don't work

```
SELECT SUM(Orders) FROM MyBuyers
```

this query works fine, but i must subtract orders where ID 80

Comment: Show some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Orders) FROM MyBuyers WHERE ID!=80
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that?

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN ID <> 80 THEN Orders ELSE -1*Orders END) AS totalAmount
FROM MyBuyers
```

**So far, what I've understood:**

You want to sum up all the orders except orders having `ID = 80`.

If ID is equal to 80 then you want to subtract the orders from the aggregated result.

---

Consider this set of sample input

```
ID   Orders
1      5
21     5
23     5
80     4
```

If your expected output for this given set of input is `11` then the above query is best fit for this.

And if your expected output is `15` then adopt the following query instead:

`SELECT SUM(Orders) FROM MyBuyers WHERE ID <> 80`